# How do you detect what date it is on iOS in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Hi I'm writing an app that has a competition in it.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]

                      initWithTitle:@"Icon Contest!"
                      message:@"Design a 1024 x 1024 pixels icon for Example. The best one will be on the app's icon! Send them to: example@example.com."
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"More Info"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"No", nil];

[alert show];
```

I have a deadline and would like to have the app to display a different alert when the date 31st of January has finished.

Comment: Add a local notification for Feb. 1st, 2013 @ Midnight local time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As yinkou points out you can use `[NSDate date]` to get the current date. But for this it may be simpler if you look into the `-timeIntervalSinceNow` method on `NSDate`. You could do something like this:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:31];
[comps setMonth:1];
[comps setYear:2013];
NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
if ([date timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0.0) {
    //The date has passed
}
else {
    //The date hasn't passed
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`[NSDate date]` returns the current date.
Using a [NSDateComponent](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can get the details like month and day from an NSDate.

Comment: Could you please give me an example (I can't figure it out)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:31];
[components setMonth:1];
[components setYear:2013];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *releaseDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

if ([NSDate date] == releaseDate)
{
[alert show];
}
```